# Can we default the filter pane to be turned in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, filter

I want to be able to globally have the filter pane turned on in SharePoint online. Is there a library setting that sets this?

I did not see a way to do this after looking at all the options. It appears that the filter pane might be linked to user preferences and not global.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to turn ON filters pane by default using SharePoint default capabilities as there are no settings available to change the default behavior (expand/collapse) of Filters pane in list/library.

**Similar threads**:

1. [Can we expand the filter pane by default to a SharePoint library?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/can-we-expand-the-filter-pane-by-default-to-a/bf99f89c-f579-4997-9e37-671dc5a95d17)
2. [Can we expand the filter pane by default to a SharePoint document library?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/can-we-expand-the-filter-pane-by-default-to-a-sharepoint/m-p/2181721)